# How to calculate this derivative in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ and a function from generalized linear group to generalized linear group
$$f: \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}), g\mapsto g^TAg$$
For $\forall Y\in\text{T}_g\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, what is 
$$D_gf(Y)$$
(I asked this question before, but everyone was voting down against it... I don't know why.. It is just an ordinary question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$**Hint**: If $M$ is an open subset of a Cartesian space $\Reals^{N}$ (e.g., $GL(n, \Reals) \subset \Reals^{n \times n}$) and $f:M \to \Reals^{N}$ is a smooth mapping, then
$$
D_{g}f(Y) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(g + tY).
$$
In your situation, $f(g) = g^{T}Ag$.

Comment: In my book, they defined the differentiation like this: $f: M\to N, D_pf: T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$. Differentiation is I understand a transformation map from a tangent space to another. Because tangent space is also (isomorphic to) vector space, we can write the transformation map as a matrix. So in this case, is what you wrote above equivalent to what i described?

Comment: What you've written isn't a definition of differentiation, just a specification of the domain and target spaces. If you're working in a general manifold, and if $\gamma$ is a smooth path in $M$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = g$ and $\gamma'(0) = Y$, then $Df$ is often defined by$$Df_{g}(Y) = (f \circ \gamma)'(0),$$which is the "invariant" version of the formula I wrote.